# Получение евентов из Вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api

У меня есть потребность сохранять в базе лайки, поставленные на посты. Подскажите, есть ли возможость подписаться на события добавления/удаления лайков по API?
Чтобы не каждый раз запрашивать всю информацию по постам, а лишь получать уведомления об изменениях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У ВКонтакте есть [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), но среди них нет уведомлений о новых/удаленных лайках. Актуальный список событий есть тут: [vk.com/dev/groups_events](https://vk.com/dev/groups_events)

Реализовать сохранение лайков можно только постоянно запрашивая актуальные списки и сравнивая их с предыдущими.

Comment: супер-неудобно :(